# Testing a Grails 3 interceptor's before method

Tags: grails

I have a test that uses the 'withInterceptors' method to invoke the interceptors for a controller before calling a given method. How can I assert what the before() method of one of those interceptors returns? Or is there a better way to invoke an interceptor for testing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can invoke the before method directly on the injected interceptor object

```
@TestFor(AuthInterceptor)
class AuthInterceptorSpec extends Specification {

    void "Invalid token fails auth"() {
        when:
        withRequest(controller:"book")
        interceptor.request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer FOOBAR")

        then:
        !interceptor.before()
    }

    void "Valid token passes auth"() {
        when:
        withRequest(controller:"book")
        interceptor.request.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,"Bearer someValidToken")

        then:
        interceptor.before()
}
```